# typescript types definition with react difficulties

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-hooks

I am trying to convert some of my old javascript code to typescript and I know I need to have all my types defined but here I have been having trouble because even if I define them I get an error.

This error is without the types defined on mapRef and current which are the two things that typescript is shouting me about.

> Object is possibly 'undefined'.

This is the code without type definitions

```
const mapRef = React.useRef();
  const onMapLoad = React.useCallback((map) => {
    mapRef.current = map;
  }, []);
  
  const panTo = React.useCallback(({ lat, lng }) => {
    mapRef.current.panTo({ lat, lng }); // This line is shouting the error
    mapRef.current.setZoom(14); // This line is shouting the error
  }, []);
```

The way I have tried to define the types is as follows:

```
A) mapRef<Number>.current<Number>.panTo({ lat, lng });
B) mapRef<Any>.current<Any>.setZoom(14);
C) mapRef?.current?.panTo({ lat, lng });
```

But all of this presents new problems and errors...
These are the error that I am getting if I do any of these

> A) 'mapRef' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof mapRef'?

> B) Type 'MutableRefObject' has no signatures for which the type argument list is applicable.

> C) Property 'panTo' does not exist on type 'never'.

Any help or any post, or documentation links are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to explicitly tell TypeScript what you're going to box into the ref. I also explicitly default it to `null` here; you could use `undefined` too.

Assuming `map` is of type `MyMap`,

```
const mapRef = React.useRef<MyMap | null>(null);
const onMapLoad = React.useCallback((map) => {
  mapRef.current = map;
}, []);
  
const panTo = React.useCallback(({ lat, lng }) => {
  const map = mapRef.current;
  if(!map) return;  // No map (yet)? (This return narrows the type of `map` from `MyMap | null` to just `MyMap`, so the following work.)
  map.panTo({ lat, lng });
  map.setZoom(14);
}, []);
```

should be enough.

You may also need to annotate the `onMapLoad` callback's parameter (to e.g. `MyMap` or `MyMap | null`).

Comment: Thank you, This snipped helps me! do you also happen to know why this might be happening ``Property 'setZoom' does not exist on type 'GoogleMap' ``I am using the code structure only difference is MyMap is GoogleMap?

Comment: Very much depends on where you got that `GoogleMap` type from :)